# Android: Would Adapter as inner class lead to memory leak?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, android-adapter

Would a non-static `Adapter` as inner class lead to memory leak? Code structure as below.

```java
public class XXFragment extends Fragment{

    // Data Binding of the content view.
    private XXBinding mBinding;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(...) {
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(...);
        mBinding.pager.setAdapter(new XXAdapter(...));
        return mBinding.getRoot();
    }

    private class XXAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<...>{...}

}
```

Seems references would form a cycle:

- The `Fragment` holds a reference to its `DataBinding` as a `field`.
- `DataBinding` internally holds a reference to a `RecyclerView`.
- The `RecyclerView` internally holds a reference to its `Adapter` since set.
- The `Adapter` as an instance of the `Fragment`'s inner class, internally holds a reference to the `Fragment`.

So it's like `Fragment->DataBinding->RecyclerView->Adapter->Fragment`.

Is this correct? Or would Android remove the `Adapter` from a view automatically that can break the cycle?

Comment: It would make the Fragment's class file longer than it has to be, whats wrong with keeping the adapter in a file/class of it's own? What i mean is - does it need to be a private class?

Comment: It was not designed to be reusable, it's only needed by the specific `Fragment`. Yes it could be taken out and made generic if latter development proved any necessity but the question itself is not about such design pattern or manner. Well, thanks anyway, meow.

Comment: Ahh and actually "It would make the Fragment's class file longer than it has to be" does not matter much. The previous dev have left a `Fragment` of 1500 lines and many 10-level nested/indented codes. Never dreamed of maintaining such a project. `class->inner class->method->if->try->lambda->lambda->for->if->lambda` like this.

Comment: Just because it's needed by one specific class/fragment does not answer the question `"does it need to be a private class?"`

Comment: If it don't have to be `public` or `protected` or `package-private` then it shall be `private`. That would minimize concern, at least shorten the auto complete list. Lint also follow this rule, right? Any unnecessary `public` would be warned against.